# Angular mat Dialog cant display object values

Tags: angular, angular-material, dialog, angular-ng-if

I can't display data from my object with mat-dialog.
It's really strange because with div and *ngIf everything works, however when i use mat dialog and
ng-template program doesn't see object values without *ngIf combination:

Error:

> Object is possibly 'undefined'.ngtsc(2532)
> cyclers.component.ts(9, 6): Error occurs in the template of component CyclersComponent.

When i delete *ngIf and switch selectedTeam.teamName and selectedTeam.teamDescription to selectedTeam I receive in page [Object Object]

Can u tell me what is going on here and how to fix that?

HTML

```html
<div class="main">
<h2>Cycling Teams</h2>
<div class="container">
    <div class="team" *ngFor="let team of teams;">
        <img src="{{ team.teamImage }}"[class.selected]="team === selectedTeam"  (click)="expandRiders(team)">
        <h2>{{team.teamName}}</h2> 
        </div>
        <ng-template #riderDescription>
            <mat-dialog-content>
                <h2  style="text-align: center ;" mat-dialog-title>{{ selectedTeam.teamName }}</h2>
                <p mat-typography style="text-align: left;">{{ selectedTeam.teamDescription}}</p>
                </mat-dialog-content>
            
                <mat-dialog-actions>
                    <button mat-button mat-dialog-close>Cancel</button>
                    </mat-dialog-actions>
              
        </ng-template>


</div>
</div>
```

Typescript

```js
import { Team } from './../team';
import { TEAMS } from './../list-cyclers';
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output, TemplateRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogContent, MatDialogConfig } from '@angular/material/dialog';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-cyclers',
  templateUrl: './cyclers.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cyclers.component.css']
})
export class CyclersComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild ('riderDescription') riderDescription: TemplateRef<any>;
  
  teams = TEAMS;
  selectedTeam?: Team;
  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) { }
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  expandRiders(team: Team){
    this.dialog.open(this.riderDescription);
    this.selectedTeam = team;
    console.log(this.selectedTeam);
    
    }
}
```

Comment: For your other issues you can use selectedTeam?.teamDescription in your template..

Comment: @MikeOne do you mean in ngtemplate: 
selectedTeam?.teamDescription

It doesn't work. Still got errors...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the very least, you likely need to change the order of your lines; set the selected team before opening the dialog (which needs a selected team in order to display anything).

```
this.selectedTeam = team;
this.dialog.open(this.riderDescription);
```

No good opening the dialog before you've set any values for it to read.

If you *want* to keep it that way, you'd need to throw in `*ngIf` checks for every usage of `selectedTeam` before using it.

The template is attempting to use it (`{{selectedTeam.teamName}}`) but can't because the object doesn't exist (it's `undefined`).

Comment: selectedTeam is dynamic array so *ngIf for every usage doesn't do the job
However thx for info about order of lines

Comment: selectedTeam isn't an array - it's clearly declared as a single `Team` object, to store the one team that the user has selected. The `*ngIf`s aren't practical, that was the underlying point of my statement about using it. Clearly far more ideal to appropriately set the selectedTeam at the right point in time rather than spam the template with a bajillion `*ngIf`s. Did switching the lines fix your issue? If so, please accept the answer or otherwise update your question so we can provide better help.